# Determine next working/business day with holidays

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops

I would like to determine the next working/business day and take holidays into account. For working days, I'm excluding Sundays & Saturdays. For holidays, I'm excluding an array of date objects.

I've structured a do-while loop to increment at least one day, and continue incrementing if it's a weekend or holiday. While my attempt works, I believe there's plenty of room for improvement by making use of latest node/ES syntax features. Note, I'm limited to vanilla JavaScript of any version, but preferably use modern features (e.g., arrow functions & all).

My condition for excluding weekends is:

```js
function nextWorkingDay(date) {
  do {
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
  } while (!(date.getDay() % 6));
  return date;
}
```

Combined with attempt at excluding holidays is:

```js
const holidays = [new Date(2019, 11, 24), new Date(2019, 11, 25), new Date(2019, 11, 26), new Date(2019, 11, 31), new Date(2020, 0, 1)];

function checkHolidays(holidays, date) {
  return holidays.some(function (holiday_date) {
    return date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) === holiday_date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  })
}

function nextWorkingDay(date) {
  do {
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
  } while (checkHolidays(holidays, date) || !(date.getDay() % 6));
  return date;
}
```

Though this works, I'm certain it can be simplified and drop the separate `checkHolidays` function altogether. I've struggled to implement [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) since the array of holidays has a different time to `new Date()` being passed into the function.

Any advice/suggestions for further improvement would be hugely appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: A functional [CodePen is available here](https://codepen.io/rdhar/pen/gOOWMww?editors=0012) to demo my progress so far, logging results directly to the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks just fine. If you want to use include, you could consider this approach, since the holidays array is defined by you.

```
const holidays=['2019-12-24', '2019-12-25']; //etc
```

Then you can use

```
holidays.includes(date.getFullYear()+'-'+(date.getMonth()+1)+'-'+date.getDate());
```

This way, your holidays array is also more 'human readable'.

If you really want to refactor it into one function, you can try a recursive approach.

```
function nextWorkingDay(date){
   if(date.getDay() % 6 == 0 || holidays.includes(date.getFullYear()+'-'+(date.getMonth()+1)+'-'+date.getDate())){
      return nextWorkingDay (new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate()+1)));
   }else return date;
}
```

Personally, although this recursion is cool and shorter, I prefer your original style of separating these two. In a huge project, you never know when you might need to check if it is a holiday, without caring if it is a Sunday. In this case, your holiday function will be reusable.

Note: typed on mobile on the move, code untested.. but I hope you get the idea!

Edit:
For starting on next day:
Either call the function above with the next day :p, or the modified function below

```
function nextWorkingDay(date){              
   date.setDate(date.getDate()+1);
   if(date.getDay() % 6 == 0 || holidays.includes(date.getFullYear()+'-'+(date.getMonth()+1)+'-'+date.getDate())){
      return nextWorkingDay (date);
   }else return date;
}
```

CodePen Fork:https://codepen.io/peekolo/pen/RwwLKYX?editors=0012

Comment: Thanks for your advice, it looks [much cleaner already](https://codepen.io/rdhar/pen/dyyzLdM?editors=0012) - since I'm relatively new to recursive functions, this is pretty trippy (even more impressive from your mobile)! 

Curiously, as seen from the CodePen, it's not returning any correct output, just whatever dates were initially passed in. Any ideas why?

Comment: Also, it should determine the _next_ working day, not consider the current day. This is why I originally opted for a do-while loop; is it similarly possible within this recursive function?

Comment: @Rick Sorry I was at work. Oops. Yes, I forgot setDate returns a number instead of a Date Object, so I modified the answer to be `nextWorkingDay (new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate()+1)));`. Now it should be working as expected. As for the next working day, I have modified the answer to include this!

Comment: That's brilliant! Updated the CodePen accordingly, which makes a cool comparison between the [recursive](https://codepen.io/rdhar/pen/dyyzLdM?editors=0012) and [iterative](https://codepen.io/rdhar/pen/gOOWMww?editors=0012) approach. Thanks once again for responding!